# C# Dynamically generate view and view model based on class type

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

(Note: I am using Xamarin.Forms and the Rg.Plugins.Popup extension)

Suppose I have the following views:

```
MyView1.xaml
MyView2.xaml
MyView3.xaml
```

And I have their corresponding view models:

```
MyViewModel1.cs
MyViewModel2.cs
MyViewModel3.cs
```

I'd like a method in my navigation controller to show the view based on the type.

```
NavigationController.ShowView(typeof(MyView1));
```

or maybe

```
NavigationController.ShowView(typeof(MyView1), typeof(MyViewModel1));
```

How could I implement this?

Currently I am making a list:

```
{
    List<MyView> viewList = new List<MyView>();

    MyView1 view1 = new MyView1();
    MyViewModel1 viewModel1 = new MyViewModel1();
    view1.BindingContext = viewModel1;
    viewList.Add(view1);
    // etc ...
}

static public void ShowView(Type type) 
{
    foreach (MyView v in viewList) 
    {
        if (v.GetType() == type)
        {
            // code to show the view.
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that after showing the view, when it is dismissed, it is setting itself to null.  So rather than pre-generate the views and storing them in a list, I'd like to generate new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quite easy...

```cs
public static View CreateView(Type vType, Type vmType)
{
    var view = (View)Activator.CreateInstance(vType);
    view.BindingContext = Activator.CreateInstance(vmType);
    return view;    
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you.

Comment: This works well.  Quick question - is it generally advisable to create new views/viewmodels everytime when going to a page?  Or to create the view/viewmodel once, store it in a list, and re-use it.

Comment: @Stephane what if VIewModel has a parameter constructor  , how to create VM in that case